# employe database management codings 

Tags: uml

i am doing a employee management project in dot net(c#,asp),where will i get the uml diagrams for the reference ... please help me ... if i get the documentation of tat project it will be very useful please help me friends
                       thank u

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you'll get them from your architect or the person doing the design of the code ;)

If you're asking for a tool to work in to draw them yourself, try Visio, it's pretty good for making UML diagrams.

If you're asking for a good way to generate them from the code the new Visual Studio beta has a class and sequence diagram generator built in.